# How to remove bird droppings from woven patio furniture?

Tags: cleaning, furniture, patio

We have a set of patio furniture with a steel frame, but a loosely woven cloth seating surface. Since we live in a very wooded area, a chair was recently dive-bombed. I have a bucket and scrub-brush - should I use laundry detergent, or something stronger or is there a preferred product or method?

Comment: Laundry detergent and dish soap should both be find.

Answer (score 2):

I think I would stay away from soaps that suds up a lot since it will make rinsing more difficult.  A general around-the-house cleaner should do the trick just fine - you can even use a mixture of vinegar and water.

The sooner you clean it off the better as bird droppings tend to eat away at materials over time (they will even etch car paint!)

Comment: +1 I can attest to the car paint damage, having left my car unwashed for a while, only to find the clear coat was damaged